# Difference of means

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have taken 5 measurements and know that my measurements are of the form constant+mean+error. I have calculated the standard deviation of the measurements but only want the value of the mean term without the constant. Is this statistically possible? What method should i use?

Comment: It is enlightening to consider the version of this problem where the error is negligible.  Thus, you have five identical values that you wish to express in the form constant + mean, effectively requiring the determination of *two* unknowns from knowledge only of their sum.  Do you think this is possible?  Now, how would increasing the error improve the situation?

Comment: I did not know how to do it. That it why i asked, but apparently you also believe it is not possible